# Show div in another wrapper while hovering in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hover on a div inside a wrapper to reveal some text inside another rapper.

I've had a stab at it with the following CSS, to no avail. Here's my attempt thus far:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gavinfriel/vhswx2jg/1/)

Here's what I was trying to do with CSS:

```
 /* My attempt */
 #assotxt {
   display: none;
 }

 #assodiv:hover ~ #assotxt {
   display: block !important;
   background-color: white;
 }
```

Javascript may be the way to go here, but I'm a bit of a novice in that regard.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No `#assotxt` element appears at lined jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gavinfriel/vhswx2jg/ ?

Comment: Apologies I've just updated it.

Comment: `#assotxt` is not a sibling of `#assodiv`

Comment: Yeah I noticed that why it wasn't working. Looking for an alternative approach.

Comment: You could use `:after` at `.mobileViewDiagram`

Comment: You can also make use of tooltip for this...

Answer (score 1):

you can also hide and show your required div on hover event using jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#assodiv').on( "mouseenter",function() {
  $('#assotxt').show();
  $('#assotxt').css("background-color", "white");
  $("#assotxt").appendTo($("#assotxt_target"));

});
$('#assodiv').on( "mouseleave",function() {
   $('#assotxt').hide();
 });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 32px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn.blue {
  background-color: #19ace4;
}

.btn.blue:hover {
  opacity: 0.85;
}

.btn.pill {
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
}


/* - - - MOBLE VIEW - - - */

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .mobileViewDiagram {
    display: block !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    transform: scale(0.7);
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
  }
  .HybridDiagram,
  #leftWrapper,
  #rightWrapper {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* - - - DESKOTP VIEW - - - */

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 476px;
  margin: auto;
}

div#leftWrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 476px;
  float: left;
}

div#rightWrapper {
  margin-left: 50%;
  height: 476px;
}

.diagramTextWrapper {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.HybridDiagram {
  width: 476px;
  height: 476px;
}

.HybridDiagram img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}


/* Associates */

.HybridDiagram img:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}


/* Staff */

.HybridDiagram img:nth-child(2) {
  left: 244px;
  top: 0;
}


/* Client */

.HybridDiagram img:nth-child(3) {
  left: 38px;
  top: 301px;
}

.mobileViewDiagram {
  display: none;
}

#asso:hover,
#staff:hover,
#client:hover {
  opacity: 0.85;
}

/* My attempt */
#assotxt {
  display: none;
}

#assodiv:hover ~ #assotxt {
  display: block !important;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Mobile View -->
<div class="mobileViewDiagram">
  <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/56e975d8f8baf3c1d69ac026/t/572caeb520c647e2e6e352e8/1462546101367/download.png">
</div>

<!-- Desktop View -->
<section>
  <div id="leftWrapper">
    <div class="HybridDiagram">
    <!-- HOVER TO REVEAL TEXT -->
      <div id="assodiv">
        <img id="asso" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/56e975d8f8baf3c1d69ac026/t/572ca6a5746fb9a13cdd54e0/1462544038103/a-slice.png">

      </div>
      <img id="staff" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/56e975d8f8baf3c1d69ac026/t/572ca6af746fb9a13cdd551f/1462544047951/b-slice.png">
      <img id="client" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/56e975d8f8baf3c1d69ac026/t/572ca6b4746fb9a13cdd553c/1462544052730/c-slice.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightWrapper">
     <div id="assotxt_target"></div>
    <div class="diagramTextWrapper">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eget sapien sed risus suscipit cursus. Quisque iaculis facilisis lacinia. Mauris euismod pellentesque tellus sit amet mollis. Nulla a scelerisque turpis, in gravida enim. Pellentesque sagittis
        faucibus elit, nec lobortis augue fringilla sed. Donec aliquam, mi in varius interdum, ante metus facilisis urna, in faucibus erat ex nec lectus. Cras tempus tincidunt purus, eu vehicula ante. Duis cursus vestibulum lorem.
        <a href="" class="btn pill blue" href="#">Blue Button</a>
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eget sapien sed risus suscipit cursus. Quisque iaculis facilisis lacinia. Mauris euismod pellentesque tellus sit amet mollis. Nulla a scelerisque turpis, in gravida enim. Pellentesque sagittis
        faucibus elit, nec lobortis augue fringilla sed. Donec aliquam, mi in varius interdum, ante metus facilisis urna, in faucibus erat ex nec lectus. Cras tempus tincidunt purus, eu vehicula ante. Duis cursus vestibulum lorem.
        <a href="" class="btn pill blue" href="#">Blue Button</a>
      </p>
      <!-- HOVER SHOULD REVEAL THS TEXT -->
      <div id="assotxt">
        This should appear on top of existing text inside rightWrapper.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: would be good to move the text with position according to the meaning "on top of the right wrapper" :D

Comment: @Mephiztopheles I have updated my answer but i see no meaning of having the div bottom of page then moving it to the top of the page.

Comment: The text sais "This should appear on top of existing text inside rightWrapper." this was like a joke :D but at first when i tried my js-solution i wondered why the text wasn't shown until i saw that the scrollbar was changing so i knew that the text was shown on bottom of the page

Answer (score 1):

Plain JS:

```
var assodiv = document.getElementById("assodiv"),
  assotxt = document.getElementById("assotxt");
assodiv.onmouseover = function(e) {
  assotxt.style.display = "block";
};

assodiv.onmouseout = function(e) {
  assotxt.style.display = "none";
};
```

insert this in a `<script>`-block on bottom of your body-tag

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

Add this to head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add this javascript:

```
var asso = $('#asso');

asso.on('mouseenter',function(){
  $('.diagramTextWrapper').prepend('<p class="wrapper_text">test</p>');
});

asso.on('mouseleave',function(){
  $('.wrapper_text').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`#assotxt` is not a sibling of `#assodiv`; also `:hover` should be applied at `.mobileViewDiagram` element? You can use `:hover:after` at `.mobileViewDiagram`, with  `content` set to text to be displayed. Use `top`, `left` properties to render text at appropriate position in viewport.

```
.mobileViewDiagram:hover:after {
  display: block !important;
  background-color: white;
  content:"This should appear on top of existing text inside rightWrapper.";
  position:absolute; /* use `top`, `left`, `right` to set position of `content` */
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vhswx2jg/2/

Comment: @GavinFriel The `<img>` elements within `#assodiv` do not appear to be displayed at original `html`? How would `#divasso` actually be hovered on? You could probably wrap each `<img>` within `#assodiv` within a `div`, substitute displaying the `<img>` in `#assodiv` for `.mobileViewDiagram` element; at `:hover` on `div` containing `<img>`, use approach at post.